# Insert list object into database using stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a collection `NameList` which contains multiple objects of `PersonName` class.

I want to insert that `NameList` using a stored procedure into a table `tbl_namelist` in a single insert operation. But before the insert, it must  delete all records from `tbl_namelist`.

```
public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>
{
    public NameList() : base()
    {
        Add(new PersonName("Willa", "Cather"));
        Add(new PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"));
        Add(new PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"));
        Add(new PersonName("Jules", "Verne"));
    }
}

public class PersonName
{
      private string firstName;
      private string lastName;

      public PersonName(string first, string last)
      {
          this.firstName = first;
          this.lastName = last;
      }

      public string FirstName
      {
          get { return firstName; }
          set { firstName = value; }
      }

      public string LastName
      {
          get { return lastName; }
          set { lastName = value; }
      }
}
```

Comment: And....   what have you tried?

Comment: A stored procedure can perform many things during execution, a delete followed by a table variable insert. Post what you've got and how you intend to call it, then we might be able to help.

Comment: CREATE TYPE NameType AS TABLE ( [FirstName]nvarchar(50) ,[LastNmae] nvarchar(50) );



CREATE PROCEDURE [InsertFeatures] '@NameTypeList' NameType  READONLY 
AS SET NOCOUNT ON; 
INSERT INTO tbl_namelist 
[FirstName] ([LastName] )

 SELECT * FROM @NameTypeList

Comment: First, press the edit button on your question to add code there and not in comment where is unreadable. Then this is a SELECT not an INSERT stored procedure